# Building Awesome WM, missing dependencies

Tags: 11.04, window-manager, dependencies, build, awesome

Trying to compile Awesome Window Manager on 11.04, I've done *apt-get build-dep awesome* but still get errors about missing dependencies:

```
$ make
Running cmake…
-- cat -> /bin/cat
-- ln -> /bin/ln
-- grep -> /bin/grep
-- git -> /usr/bin/git
-- hostname -> /bin/hostname
-- asciidoc -> /usr/bin/asciidoc
-- xmlto -> /usr/bin/xmlto
-- gzip -> /bin/gzip
-- lua -> /usr/bin/lua
-- luadoc -> /usr/bin/luadoc
-- convert -> /usr/bin/convert
-- checking for modules 'glib-2.0;cairo;x11;oocairo;oopango;xcb-randr;xcb-xtest;xcb-xinerama;xcb-util>=0.3.8;xcb-keysyms>=0.3.4;xcb-icccm>=0.3.8;xcb-image>=0.3.0;cairo-xcb;libstartup-notification-1.0>=0.10;xproto>=7.0.15;libxdg-basedir>=1.0.0'
--   package 'oocairo' not found
--   package 'oopango' not found
--   package 'xcb-util>=0.3.8' not found
--   package 'xcb-icccm>=0.3.8' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

I don't see any sign of these libraries in the repos.

I tried the instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=960841 and that also fails:

```
$ cd util && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:5: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:5: installing `./missing'
src/Makefile.am:1: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:1:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'
src/Makefile.am:1:   to `configure.ac' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.
src/Makefile.am:1:   If `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' is in `configure.ac', make sure
src/Makefile.am:1:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
src/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
src/Makefile.am:13: `xcbinclude_HEADERS' is used but `xcbincludedir' is undefined
Makefile.am:6: `pkgconfig_DATA' is used but `pkgconfigdir' is undefined
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

What do I need to do to be able to compile?

Comment: Why do you need to compile `awesome`? It is available in the repos. And by the way `build-dep` is for compiling a package obtained with `apt-get source <package>`.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/q/21281/101830.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to install `libxcb-icccm1-dev` package.

Comment: ... and then some, but that helped me. How did you determine it ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you miss many `-dev` packages.

In your case,  something like

> `libxcb-util*-dev` (based on the `xcb-utils` reported missing package)
>   `libxcb-icccmX-dev` as suggested by [tdi](https://askubuntu.com/a/57424/101830),  but in my case that was **`libxcb-icccm4-dev`**
>   and some `*oocairo*` and `*oopango*` packages (likely `-dev`).

Answer (score 0):

You're not required to compile, anyways like @enzotib said, youre only supposed to do that for

```
apt-get source <package>
```

Just use

```
sudo aptitude install awesome
```